# Using Retrofit multipass to process my request which include audio and some string but it has been giving error 404

Tags: android, retrofit

i have been trying to use retrofit multipart to send some parameters to the server which include audio file and some string, it has been returning error 404 to me, how do i fix it?

ere is my interface class

public interface ApiUpload {

```
String BASE_URL = "http://goodguys.com:1010";

@Multipart
@POST("Trucker/load")
Call<JsonResponse>

upload(
        @Part("audio") RequestBody file,
        @Part("userId") RequestBody userid,
        @Part("sessionid") RequestBody sessionid,
        @Part("devicetype") RequestBody devicetype,
        @Part("deviceid") RequestBody deviceid

);
```

private void doMultiFormRequest(String audioSavePathInDevice) {

```
    File audioFile = new File(audioSavePathInDevice);
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), audioFile);
    RequestBody userid = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), email);
    RequestBody sessionId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),  "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    RequestBody devicetype =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),  "android");
    RequestBody deviceid =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), MyMobile.getInstance().getImei());

    final ProgressDialog d = new ProgressDialog(this);
    d.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
    d.setCancelable(false);


    apiUpload.upload(body, userid, sessionId, devicetype, deviceid).enqueue(new JsonResponseCallback(this, d) {
         @Override
        protected void onTransactionSuccess(JsonResponse res) {

            Log.v("Responses", res.toString());

            if (d != null && d.isShowing()) {
                d.dismiss();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: 404 means link not found. please check your link and the base url should end with a `/` or start the rest of the api with a `/`. Use `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to log your network calls in logcat

Answer (score 1):

404 is response code from server. Seems like something is wrong with the url you are posting to.

Is there a slash missing?

```
@POST("/Trucker/load")
```

Comment: it is not the slash, i am believing that the issue is within the context of the Request Mutlipart